# Were Michael Ende’s books translated into English?

Tags: books, translation, michael-ende

As a child/teen I read *The Neverending Story* as well as several other books by the same author. I know that the former was adapted into a film (possibly two films), and I presume that the novel was also translated into English.

Still, native English readers I have spoken with don't seem familiar with Michael Ende beyond this one book - or rather the film of the book. Were they never translated, or are the translations out of print? It seems highly unusual to translate only one novel by an author.

Comment: No. No film was ever made of *The Neverending Story*. It is a book, and only a book, and will always remain so.

Comment: The first and only movie covered about a half of the book's content. We can suppose an hypothetical second movie would have dealt with the other half of the book. This would have left nothing (_the_ Nothing?) for a third movie, which therefore we must exclude altogether from the realm of possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

The [“Selected Works” section of his Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Ende#Selected_works) highlights works that were translated into English. Here are the items which were translated into English:

> - 1960 - *Jim Knopf und Lukas der Lokomotivführer* (Translated into English by Anthea Bell as *Jim Button and Luke the Engine Driver*)
> - 1973 - *Momo* (1973) (Translated into English by Francis Lobb as *The Grey Gentlemen*, and by J. Maxwell Brownjohn as *Momo*.)
> - 1978 *Das Traumfresserchen* (Translated into English by Gwen Mars as *The Dream Eater* in 1978)
> - 1979 - *Die unendliche Geschichte: Von A bis Z* (Translated into English by Ralph Manheim as *The Neverending Story*)
> - 1984 - *Der Spiegel im Spiegel* (1986) (Translated into English by J. Maxwell Brownjohn as *Mirror in the Mirror: a labyrinth* in 1986)
> - 1988 - *Ophelias Schattentheater* (Translated into English by Anthea Bell as *Ophelia's Shadow Theater* in 1989)
> - 1989 - *Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch* (Translated into English by Heike Schwarzbauer and Rick Takvorian as *The Night of Wishes: or, The Satanarchaeolidealcohellish Notion Potion* in 1992)

There may be English translations which Wikipedia is unaware of. Also note that this only lists translations *of an entire work*; there may be fragments which aren’t listed here.